# It's possible use socket.io with Astro framework?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, astrojs

I am trying to use socket.io with Astro, I have had some problems with socket.io, I can connect and send a message to an event, but when I try to subscribe to an event in my frontend to send it to the screen I do not receive it.

main.astro (frontend)

```
---
import Header from "../components/header.astro";
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
import Sidebar from "../components/sidebar.astro";
---

<Layout title="EnteraChat">
  <Sidebar />
  <div class="content-container">
    <Header />

    <div class="chat-container chat-container-with-margin">
      <!-- aqui se mustran los mensajes del chat -->
      <div id="chat"><ul></ul></div>

      <form
        id="messageForm"
        class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 form-full-width"
      >
        <input
          id="messageInput"
          type="text"
          class="block mx-4 p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
          placeholder="Your message..."
        />

        <button
          type="submit"
          class="inline-flex justify-center p-2 text-blue-600 rounded-lg cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-100 dark:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
        >
          <svg
            class="w-5 h-5 rotate-90"
            aria-hidden="true"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="currentColor"
            viewBox="0 0 18 20"
          >
            <path
              d="m17.914 18.594-8-18a1 1 0 0 0-1.828 0l-8 18a1 1 0 0 0 1.157 1.376L8 18.281V9a1 1 0 0 1 2 0v9.281l6.758 1.689a1 1 0 0 0 1.156-1.376Z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
          <span class="sr-only">Send message</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-c79GN5VsunZvi+Q/WObgk2in0CbZsHnjEqvFxC5DxHn9lTfNce2WW6h2pH6u/kF+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    // Conectar al servidor de Socket.io
    const socket = io("http://192.168.35.16:8000");

    const form = document.querySelector("#messageForm"); // # indica un selector de id
const input = document.querySelector("#messageInput");
const mensajes = document.querySelector("ul"); // Asegúrate de que este selector sea correcto

    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (input.value) {
    console.log('Enviando mensaje:', input.value);
    socket.emit('chat', input.value);
    input.value = '';
  }
});

    socket.on('chat', (msg) => {
  console.log('Mensaje recibido del servidor:', msg);

  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.textContent = msg;
  mensajes.appendChild(item);
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});
   
  </script>

  <style>
    /* Estilo base para .chat-container */
    .chat-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 69vh;
      margin-left: 0; /* Inicialmente, sin margen izquierdo */
      transition: margin-left 0.3s ease; /* Agrega una transición suave para el margen izquierdo */
    }

    /* Aplica el margen izquierdo solo cuando el sidebar esté abierto */
    .chat-container.chat-container-with-margin {
      margin-left: 250px;
    }

    #chat {
      flex-grow: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 85vh;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #messageForm {
      width: auto;
      height: 15vh;
    }

    #chat p {
      width: 70%;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    /* Estilo para mensajes del usuario actual (derecha) */
    #chat .me {
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: #4861d1;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-align: right; /* Alinea el texto a la derecha */
    }

    /* Estilo para mensajes de otros usuarios (izquierda) */
    #chat .them {
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: #67acec;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-align: left; /* Alinea el texto a la izquierda */
    }

    #chat .username-me {
      margin-left: auto;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    #chat .username-them {
      margin-right: auto;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</Layout>
```

index.js (server)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const { instrument } = require('@socket.io/admin-ui');
const cors = require('cors');

const messageModel = require('./models/messageModel');

app.use(express.json());
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Configurar CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:4321', 'https://admin.socket.io'];
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin) || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('No permitido por CORS'));
    }
  },
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
  credentials: true
}));

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:4321', 'https://admin.socket.io'];
      if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin) || !origin) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error('No permitido por CORS'));
      }
    },
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true
  }
});

instrument(io, {
  auth: false
});

// // Incluir esta línea para servir la biblioteca Socket.io
// app.use('/socket.io', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist'));

// Importar rutas
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const roomTypeRoutes = require('./routes/roomTypeRoutes');
const roomRoutes = require('./routes/roomRoutes');
const roomUserRoutes = require('./routes/roomUserRoutes');
const messageTypeRoutes = require('./routes/messageTypeRoutes');
const messageRoutes = require('./routes/messageRoutes');

// Rutas
app.use('/api', userRoutes);
app.use('/api', roomTypeRoutes);
app.use('/api', roomRoutes);
app.use('/api', roomUserRoutes);
app.use('/api', messageTypeRoutes);
app.use('/api', messageRoutes);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Cliente conectado');

  socket.on('join room', (data) => {
    // Unir al cliente a la sala correspondiente
    socket.join(data.room_id);
    console.log(`Cliente unido a la sala ${data.room_id}`);
  });

  socket.on('chat', async (messageData) => {
    // Convierte room_id en un entero
    const room_id = parseInt(messageData.room_id);
    console.log("mensaje recibido", messageData);
  
    try {
      // Agrega registros para verificar la sala a la que se envía el mensaje
      console.log("Enviando mensaje a la sala:", messageData.room_id);
  
      io.to(room_id).emit('chat', messageData);
      console.log("mensaje emitido a todos los clientes en la sala", messageData);
  
      // Llama a la función createMessage para insertar el mensaje en la base de datos
      const messageId = await messageModel.createMessage(messageData);
  
      // Agrega el ID del mensaje al objeto de datos
      messageData.id = messageId;
    } catch (error) {
      // Maneja cualquier error que ocurra al guardar en la base de datos
      console.error('Error al guardar el mensaje en la base de datos:', error);
  
      // Maneja el error al emitir el mensaje a la sala
      console.error('Error al emitir el mensaje a la sala:', error);
  
    }
  });

  // Manejar la desconexión de un cliente
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Cliente desconectado');
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor en ejecución en el puerto:`, PORT);
});
```

several things like creating other projects without astro and I can connect, but according to me there should be no problem using socket.io and astro.